# Как получить свой проект с git'a

Tags: git, github

Пытаюсь сделать свое приложение но походу то, что делал на компьютере не то. Как мне назад вернуть, то что осталось на гите. Commit и push  не делал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то тут очень радикальные меры предлагают.

Если вы ничего не коммитили и не пушили, вам поможет простое:

```
git checkout .
```

> Git, вытяни всю текущую папку из текущего коммита

Так все файлы, отслеживаемые гитом, будут возвращены в старое состояние, актуальное для последнего сделанного коммита.

Если вы хотите почистить ещё и неотслеживаемые файлы, вам потребуется ещё одно из:

```
git clean -n # Проверить, что удалилось бы (абсолютно безопасно)
git clean -i # Почистить, спрашивая про каждый файл (рекомендую)
git clean -f # Зачистить всё неотслеживаемое (если файлов много)
```

Но учтите, что для `git clean` по-прежнему работают правила игнорирования из `.gitignore`. Чтобы преодолеть это и, возможно, какие-то ещё проблемы, посмотрите [инструкцию по clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто откатить локальную ветку до состояния удаленной:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Довольно крупнокалиберное действие с учётом того, что ТС коммитов якобы не делал.

Answer (score -2):

Если хочешь вернуть проект на локальной машине до состояние как на гите, думаю можно просто снести его на локальной машине и клонировать его с репозитория.

```
git clone [REPO URL] .
```

Comment: А для того, чтобы удалить файлы с компьтера, Вы сносите ОС и ставите ее заново?